# How to execute DB2 sql script that contains a CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR statement

Tags: db2, cursor, resultset, db2-luw

Below is the sample PL/SQL block that i want to execute in a sql script.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_emp_nbr   SMALLINT;

BEGIN

    DECLARE RESULT_CURSOR  CURSOR WITH RETURN  FOR

    SELECT
      EMP_NAME,
      EMP_JOIN_DATE,
      EMP_DESIG
    FROM  EMPLOYEE
    WITH UR FOR READ ONLY;

    OPEN RESULT_CURSOR ;
END;
END
```

I am receiving the below error when i try to execute through script.

42601(-109)[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0109N  The "TO CALLER" clause is not allowed.

Comment: are you sure this is the code that is getting the error?  I don't think so, you don't have the string "TO CALLER" anywhere in your code.

Comment: `TO CALLER` is the implicit default options @Hogan

Comment: @mustaccio -- implicit default options that are not allowed?

Comment: I'm just saying where `TO CALLER` is coming from.

Comment: I suspect cursors `WITH RETURN` are not supported in standalone compound SQL statements (anonymous blocks), because there is no "caller" in the sense that the proper PSM call sequence is not set up. Try creating a stored procedure instead.

Comment: The reason I asked this to be able to test the SP without binding to DB. I used to do this with Oracle SQL Developer but not sure how to do it in DB2. @mustaccio